# Timers' methods with different intervals run at the same time frequently

Tags: c#, timer

I have two timers running at different intervals. `t1` is 5 minutes, `t2` is 3, 4 or 8 minutes(changed in the Tick method randomly). As I understand it, the Tick-method is called for `t2` then I assign a new value for the interval for it to then wait this interval till it is called again.

But more often than not, `t1_Tick` and `t2_Tick` are run at the same time.

Here is the code

```
private void t2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    t2.Interval = w * 60000; //w is 3, 4 or 8
}


private void los()
{
    if (btnAktivieren.Text == "Aktivieren")
    {
        t2.Interval = w * 60000; //w is 3, 4 or 8
        t2.Enabled = true;
        t1.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        t2.Enabled = false;
        t1.Enabled = false;
    }
}


private void t1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Here are the timers

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer t1;
this.t1.Enabled = true;
this.t1.Interval = 300000;
this.t1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.t1_Tick);


private System.Windows.Forms.Timer t2;
this.t2.Enabled = true;
this.t2.Interval = 9000;
this.t2.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.t2_Tick);
```

Why is that?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: @PeterBons Done.

Comment: What's the value of w in `w * 60000`

Comment: @3dd 3, 4 or 8 ...